# How to query and sort natually in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting, natural-sort

I have a `mongoDB`containing millions of documents.

I want to query the database and sort the results naturally using a specific field.

From Mongo documentation it seems that only naive sort supported.
Is there a way to sort naturally?

Example:

- doc 1 _id: "abc10.def"
- doc 2 _id: "abc2.def"
- doc 3 _id: "abc1.def"

Query:
`db_collection.find({}).sort({_id: 1})`

returns a list by order:

- doc3 ("abc1.def")
- doc1 ("abc10.def")
- doc2 ("abc2.def")

how can I sort to receive the following list?:

- doc3 ("abc1.def")
- doc2 ("abc2.def")
- doc1 ("abc10.def")

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/#metaOp._S_natural

Comment: @Astro: Can you give more info how to use it? I also found the mongo documentation, but wasn't able to understand how to use it.

Comment: @Astro: running your statement doesn't yield the expected

Comment: @Astro `$natural` returns the documents in the order in which the database refers to them on disk. Please read the question and decide if that's really what OP needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that shorter strings should be returned before longer ones and then you should sort alphabetically strings that have the same length. To do that you need a temporary field `length` which can be added using [$strLenBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenBytes/index.html).

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            length: { $strLenBytes: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            length: 1, _id: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            length: 0
        }
    }
])
```